# what the difference between qs and querystring

Tags: node.js

There is a function `bodyparser.urlencoded(options)` in `body-parser`, it has a option called extended.

> The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded
>   data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when
>   true). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be
>   encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like
>   experience with URL-encoded. For more information, please see the qs
>   library.

I had read `qs` and `querystring` document but I could not find any obvious difference, so I am asking for help here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690436/3290143

Answer (score 64):

### Let's check them together:

### Query String

> The querystring module provides utilities for parsing and formatting
> URL query strings.

#### [Node.js v10.0.0 Documentation : API : Query String](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

**It is part of the NodeJS API, introduced in `v0.1.25`**.

We can observe it has 4 main function : **`escape, parse, stringify, unescape`**

(all the functions except the `parse` function have been the same since **`v0.1.25`**.)

> **~ History of `querystring.parse`** :

```
    Version     Changes
     v8.0.0      Multiple empty entries are now parsed correctly (e.g. &=&=).
     v6.0.0      The returned object no longer inherits from Object.prototype.
     v4.2.4      The eq parameter may now have a length of more than 1.
```

As you can see it is a **simple** solution for its main purpose.

---

### `qs` module :

> A querystring parsing and stringifying library with some added
> security.

#### [NPM Package : `qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)  ([Github Repo.](https://github.com/ljharb/qs))

(**At the time of writing this**)

- Last Updated : 2 days ago
- [Open issues](https://github.com/ljharb/qs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20)  : 28
  ( [of which **7** are labeled as `bug`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Abug) )

Lets just have a glimpse at the `qs.parse` function :

> qs allows you to create nested objects within your query strings, by
> surrounding the name of sub-keys with square brackets []. For example,
> the string 'foo[bar]=baz' converts to:

```
assert.deepEqual(qs.parse('foo[bar]=baz'), {
>     foo: {
>         bar: 'baz'
>     } });
```

> 

Compared to Query String, it is able of parsing nested objects...

> By default, when nesting objects qs will only parse up to 5 children
> deep. This means if you attempt to parse a string like
> 'a[b][c][d][e][f][g][h][i]=j' your resulting object will be:
>
> ```
> var expected = {
>     a: {
>         b: {
>             c: {
>                 d: {
>                     e: {
>                         f: {
>                             '[g][h][i]': 'j'
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

The depth can be overridden :

```
var deep = qs.parse('a[b][c][d][e][f][g][h][i]=j', { depth: 8 });
```

...and this is just one of the many features that this package offers, compared to *Query String*

[The `qs.stringify` function has also many more options](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying)

I would say `qs` is an **advanced** solution.

---

## Question :

> I had read `qs` and `querystring` document but I could not find any
> obvious difference, so I am asking for help here.

## Answer :

They are not different in terms of purpose.

**`querystring` has some limits, but at the end, that is depending on your needs...**

Comment: You can test the differences between `qs` and `querystring` in this sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-xa27zd?file=index.js

Answer (score 10):

To be simple,
`querystring` cannot parse nested object.

Instead, it will be presented in `[]` format.

While `qs` can be parsed in nested object.