# What does 'extended' mean in express 4.0?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm using express and also body-parser in my app.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

But, What does 'extended' mean in express 4.0?

I found this

```
extended - parse extended syntax with the qs module.
```

However, I still can't understrand what it means.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

If `extended` is `false`, you can not post "nested object"

```
person[name] = 'cw'

// Nested Object = { person: { name: cw } }
```

If `extended` is `true`, you can do whatever way that you like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175465/body-parser-extended-option-qs-vs-querystring/29177740#29177740 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960764/what-does-extended-mean-in-express-4-0/45690436#45690436

Answer (score 153):

> When `extended` property is set to **`true`**, the URL-encoded data will
> be parsed with the [qs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs).

On the contrary,

> when `extended` property is set to **`false`**, the URL-encoded data will
> instead be parsed with the [query-string library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).

---

### The differences between parsing with `qs library` vs `querystring library`

- **qs** library allows you to create a **nested** object from your query string.

  ```
    var qs = require("qs")
    var result = qs.parse("person[name]=bobby&person[age]=3")
    console.log(result) // { person: { name: 'bobby', age: '3' } }
  ```
- **query-string** library **does not** support creating a nested object from your query string.

  ```
    var queryString = require("query-string")
    var result = queryString.parse("person[name]=bobby&person[age]=3")
    console.log(result) // { 'person[age]': '3', 'person[name]': 'bobby' }
  ```

- **qs** library will **not** filter out '?' from the query string.

  ```
    var qs = require("qs")
    var result = qs.parse("?a=b")
    console.log(result) // { '?a': 'b' }
  ```

- **query-string** library will filter out '?' from the query string.

  ```
    var queryString = require("query-string")
    var result = queryString.parse("?a=b")
    console.log(result) // { a: 'b' }
  ```

---

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

For more information, you may refer to [Leonid Beschastny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175465/body-parser-extended-option-qs-vs-querystring/29177740#29177740).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960764/what-does-extended-mean-in-express-4-0

Answer (score 25):

From the Body-Parser docs:

> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body). This object will contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array (when extended is false), or any type (when extended is true).

And

> The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The "extended" syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded. For more information, please see the qs library.

Basically extended allows you to parse full objects.

[Body Parser: Url Encoded](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparser-urlencoded-options)