# Non-deprecated alternative to body-parser in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am going through the book *Web Development with Node and Express* and have hit a snag.

I was instructed to put the below in my application file, but it looks like `body-parser` is deprecated and will not work. How can I achieve the same functionality?

This is my current code:

```
app.use(require('body-parser')());

app.get('/newsletter', function(req, res){

    // we will learn about CSRF later...for now, we just
    // provide a dummy value
    res.render('newsletter', { csrf: 'CSRF token goes here' });
});

app.post('/process', function(req, res){

    console.log('Form (from querystring): ' + req.query.form); 
    console.log('CSRF token (from hidden form field): ' + req.body._csrf); 
    console.log('Name (from visible form field): ' + req.body.name); 
    console.log('Email (from visible form field): ' + req.body.email); res.redirect(303, '/thank-you');
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bodyParser is deprecated express 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From: [bodyParser is deprecated express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4)

It means that using the bodyParser() constructor has been deprecated, as of 2014-06-19.

```
app.use(bodyParser()); //Now deprecated
```

You now need to call the methods separately

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And so on.

Comment: When I replace app.use(require('body-parser')()); with app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.json()); I get body parser not defined.

Answer (score 21):

Just wanted to update this thread because I tried the solution above and received undefined. Express 4.16+ has implemented their own version of body-parser so you do not need to add the dependency to your project. You can run it natively in express as follows:

```js
app.use(express.json()); // Used to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // Parse URL-encoded bodies using query-string library
// or
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Parse URL-encoded bodies using qs library
```

Source: [Express JS — body-parser and why may not need it](https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c)

See also: [query-string vs qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960764/what-does-extended-mean-in-express-4-0/45690436#45690436)

Comment: Nice, i did not needed the urlencoded line, removed, because it triggers a warn of deprecation in 4.17

Answer (score 4):

**Do not use body-parser anymore**

Since Express 4.16+ the body parsing functionality has become **builtin** with express

So, you can simply do

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

from directly express, without having to install body-parser.

you can now uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**And to get the POST data content, you can use `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or if body comes as string,

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```