# MEAN Stack Angular 2 update(put) function is not running

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I'm not sure why i'm having this weird error. I'm using route.put and selected PUT on my post man.

Here's my post man error:
Image link->https://ibb.co/dzvAKc

All of my musics on my mongoDB data: Image link->https://ibb.co/d9TY5H

Routes:

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const Music = require('../models/music');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/database.js');
module.exports = (router) => {
```

Update function:

```
router.put('/updateMusic', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body._id) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No music id provided.'});
    }
    else { .. more authentications here }

return router;
};
```

Somehow it can't get pass that 1st if.

[UPDATE] :

Here's the img for the headers-> https://ibb.co/mGr9vH

Comment: can you check this post to see if your problem is not related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128238/how-can-i-read-the-data-received-in-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-format-on . Thx

Comment: i already use body-parse, also my registration form is already running, and can also retrieve the data on my edit form. i'm not really sure why seems can't i get the id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your have a typo here :

```
router.put('/updateMusic', (req, res) => {
    // if (!req.body._id) { <-- HERE _id, but it seems its id 
    if (!req.body.id)
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No music id provided.'});
    }
    else { .. more authentications here }

return router;
};
```

Comment: Update: yes i do use. here's the link for the img->https://ibb.co/mGr9vH

Answer (score 0):

Replace `req.body._id` with `req.body.id`
Also - do you have `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` ?
You are sending request with `Content-Type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so this line will parse this and assign data to `body` property