# Form sending empty object

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to create a REST with express, typescript and ejs as view engine for showing the data in the frontend. I have created a form in ejs:

```html
<form action="/app" method="post">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <input name="url" placeholder="Url" class="form-control">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description"
                                  class="form-control"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">
            Send
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this form send a POST request to the route `/app` and this is the function that should be executed then:

```js
public async saveLink(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {    
    console.log(req.body)
    const {title, url, description} = req.body;
    const newLink = new LinkModel({title, url, description});
    await newLink.save();
    res.json({status: res.status, data: newLink});
}
```

An in the console, the function prints:

```
{} 
(node:22256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: LinkModel validation failed: title: Path `title` is required., url: Path `url` is required.
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\Trabajo\Programación\Yt-video-keeper\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2574:32)
    at C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\Trabajo\Programación\Yt-video-keeper\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2394:17
    at C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\Trabajo\Programación\Yt-video-keeper\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1181:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:22256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As you can see, its prints req.body as a empty object, so the data is not recived. But when I send the data throught POSTMAN, it works fine and save the object to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [sending data via an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data), you should take into concern the request's headers.

In this case the relevant header is:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Which means the request body you receive on the server side won't be of JSON format (and therefore is parsed into an empty object).

Hence, in order to use the request's body like you did, you first need to parse it.
Luckily, you can use some external library that'll transform it to JSON format, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128238/how-can-i-read-the-data-received-in-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-format-on).