# how to perform operations with json string from axios?

Tags: node.js, json, axios

**Background**

I am passing variable from my frontend HTML file using axios

```js
var idToken1 = result.getIdToken();
                    
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/trial',
  data: idToken1,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
.then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
});
```

in my app.js under route getting this as output,here all the values are present in key and key values is empty. so i think i need a way to parse those keys first

```
 {
      '{"payload":{"cognito:username":"jatin","exp":1620965984,"iat":1620962384,"email":"xxxx@gmail.com"}}': ''
    }
```

i want to extract `"email":"xxxx@gmail.com"`

update: in app.js i am already using express native parser app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded({     extended: true }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `axios`. axios needed object to be send as json object.
var idToken1 = result.getIdToken();

the following code results in proper JSON object in my backend

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/trial',
  data: { idToken: idToken1 },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(function (response) {
  //handle success
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
  //handle error
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A [parser is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129247/3957754) if you want to get the http body as object:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Then you can use `req.body` to get the http body sent by your html web:

```
app.post('/trial', function(req, res) {
  var email = req.body.payload.email;
  //etc
});
```

Comment: I am already using `app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));`
updated my question

Comment: order is very important. Take a look to this sample https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-express-snippets/blob/master/04-post-endpoint.js

Comment: i corrected my order too but still when i do req.body.payload it shows undefined in the console.
did you check my json string, it is inthis general form `{ ''{"payload":{"cognito:username":"jatin","exp":1620965984,"iat":1620962384,"email":"xxxx@gmail.com"}}' : ' '  }`.
here all the values are present in key and key values is empty.
so i think i need a way to parse those keys first?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--MuvkO3GC--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://thepracticaldev.s3.amazonaws.com/i/coe8u0vt3iryp70e1rdv.png), x-www-form-urlencoded is used to send key=value, not for complex objects. You are sending `data: idToken1` in which `idToken1` is an object. You have two options: #1 use application/json as content-type or #2  convert **idToken1** to key=value before sending using axios. Advice :  test your /trial with postman to validate if the error is in your axios side or in the /trial

Comment: SO true. your #1 method return empty object however #2 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem cause is **'Content-Type'**
is should be **'application/json'**

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/trial',
        data: idToken1,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
        });
```