# Decode JSON object in req where content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: node.js, json, express, req

I have integration with payment service, and he send me a curl like this
`curl -d '{"merchantAccount":"pipedrive_youscore_rubicon_ltd","orderReference":"WFP-BTN-7181819-635e48482b33d","merchantSignature":"7bff82ec724b2a3ade7fe74e3b829f2c","amount":3,"currency":"UAH","authCode":"326470","email":"rubicon.sergii@gmail.com","phone":"380669114250","createdDate":1667123272,"processingDate":1667123284,"cardPan":"44****6705","cardType":"Visa","issuerBankCountry":"Ukraine","issuerBankName":"MONObank","recToken":"","transactionStatus":"Approved","reason":"Ok","reasonCode":1100,"fee":0.07,"paymentSystem":"googlePay","acquirerBankName":"WayForPay","cardProduct":"credit","clientName":"Rubicon Sergii","products":[{"name":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0439 \u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440","price":3,"count":1}],"clientFields":[{"name":"\u0414\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d \u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0443","value":"rawgsag"}]}' http://app.rubicon.tips:3000/checkSupPay`

Where content type `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

And on server i have next req.body

```
 body: [Object: null prototype] {
    "'{merchantAccount:pipedrive_youscore_rubicon_ltd,orderReference:WFP-BTN-7181819-635e48482b33d,merchantSignature:7bff82ec724b2a3ade7fe74e3b829f2c,amount:3,currency:UAH,authCode:326470,email:rubicon.sergii@gmail.com,phone:380669114250,createdDate:1667123272,processingDate:1667123284,cardPan:44****6705,cardType:Visa,issuerBankCountry:Ukraine,issuerBankName:MONObank,recToken:,transactionStatus:Approved,reason:Ok,reasonCode:1100,fee:0.07,paymentSystem:googlePay,acquirerBankName:WayForPay,cardProduct:credit,clientName:Rubicon Sergii,products:[{name:\\u0422\\u0435\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0438\\u0439 \\u0442\\u043e\\u0432\\u0430\\u0440,price:3,count:1}],clientFields:[{name:\\u0414\\u043e\\u043c\\u0435\\u043d \\u043f\\u043e\\u0440\\u0442\\u0430\\u043b\\u0443,value:rawgsag}]}'": ''
  },
```

I think this `req.body` parsed like `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` but in body json object, how to parse it?

I trying parse with `express.urlencoded({ extended: false })` `express.urlencoded({ extended: false, type: 'application/json' })` and
`express.json({ strict: false, type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })` with all options, but i cant parse it correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

// With body-parser configured, now create our route. We can grab POST 
// parameters using req.body.variable_name

// POST http://localhost:8080/api/books
// parameters sent with 
app.post('/api/books', function(req, res) {
    var book_id = req.body.id;
    var bookName = req.body.token;
    //Send the response back
    res.send(book_id + ' ' + bookName);
});
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/42129247/17278956

Comment: Its doesn't work ((