# NodeJs: How to parse post request body

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to use `body-parser` but it's deprecated so I'm doing this

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
  })
)
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/send-message', (req, res) => {
console.log('request', req.body);
res.sendStatus(200)
})

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server is listening on port', server.address().port)
})
```

And send post request from Postman

[image]

But in the console I get

```
server is listening on port 3000
request {}
```

Why request is empty? and how to catch it correctly?

Comment: Provide the `Content-Type: application/json` header when making your Postman request. (If I remember correctly, that "Text" dropdown has a "JSON" option that populates this header for you)

Comment: How did you try to use body-parser ?

Comment: Does it answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126189/non-deprecated-alternative-to-body-parser-in-express-js ? Here are more references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330014/bodyparser-is-deprecated-express-4

Comment: thanks to you @George that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select json from the dropdown menu where text is written, this will set the content-type header to application/json
[text to json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxu8K.png)