# how to read req.body containing array

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express 4.16.

```
app.use(express.json());
...
router.post('/add', function (req, res, next) {
    var course = req.body;
    console.log(course);
});
```

the result looks like:

```
 { 
  course_name: 'xxx',
  course_start_date: '01-02-2019',
  course_end_date: '15-02-2019',
  'days[0][dayIdx]': '1',
  'days[0][from]': '16:45',
  'days[0][to]': '17:00',
  'days[1][dayIdx]': '2',
  'days[1][from]': '17:45',
  'days[1][to]': '17:30' 
 }
```

what i'm looking for is having the following:

```
 { 
  course_name: 'xxx',
  course_start_date: '01-02-2019',
  course_end_date: '15-02-2019',
  'days':[
      {'dayIdx': '1', 'from': '16:45', 'to': '17:00'},
      {'dayIdx': '2', 'from': '17:45', 'to': '17:30'}
    ] 
 }
```

the input I send to the node is already contains an Array:
[image]

any elegant way or a library rather than iterating the keys and create the arrays manually?

Comment: The elegant solution is to _send_ the data in the correct format provided you write the server code.

Comment: @marekful - already did. I've update my question with screenshot of the request data

Comment: Can you please add the request headers you are sending? Specifically the `content-type` of the request.

Comment: I didn't pass any headers... when I do pass application/json, than the request failed. I assume it because something in express.json() - I don't get any stacktrace, just '400' as status code @alex-rokabilis

Comment: Is it possible that you are sending `formdata`? Can you post the full code that you are using to send the request? Also try with postman to see if the error remains.

Comment: Try to set the "extended : true" option at the json parser.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960764/what-does-extended-mean-in-express-4-0