# how to fix [Object: null prototype] { title: 'product' }

Tags: angular, javascript, node.js, express

I've started learning `node.js` with `express` framework ,  when I post a form like this :

```js
router.get('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST" ><input type="text" name="title" /><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>');
});
     
router.post('/product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

When I do `console.log(req.body)` it displays:

```
[Object: null prototype] { title: 'product' }
```

instead of just  `{ title: 'product' }`

I'm wondering if this actually is an error with express or just a propriety that its been added to express recently , because I downloaded another project created last year and it used the same approach, when I did `console.log(req.body)`, it displayed the same output.

Comment: change your url encoded bodyparser extended to true instead of false and that will do it.

Comment: Maximillian Schwarzemuller right?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That’s actually good design. Objects by default inherit the `Object.prototype` that contains some helper functions (`.toString()`, `.valueOf()`). Now if you use `req.body` and you pass no parameters to the HTTP request, then you'd expect `req.body` to be empty. If it were just "a regular object", it wouldn't be entirely empty:

```
console.info(({ "toString": 5 })['toString']);   // 5
console.info(({})['toString']);                  // [Function: toString]
```

There is a way to create "empty objects", meaning objects without any properties / prototype, and that is `Object.create(null)`. You are seeing one of those objects in the console.

So no, this is not a bug that needs to be fixed, that’s just great use of JS' features.

Comment: Didn't get this part here: *you pass no parameters to the HTTP request, then you'd expect req.body to be empty. If it would just be "a regular object" it wouldn't be: `req.body.toString();`*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AmitDas he means that even if `req.body` wouldn't have any "own" properties (e.g. `title` as in the example above) it would still inherit the default Object prototype and would have methods such as `toString()` making it non-empty.

Comment: Answer doesn't tell solution

Comment: "this is not a bug that needs to be fixed, that’s just great use of JS' features"                              what a sick joke!

Answer (score 54):

Try this,

```
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); // req.body = [Object: null prototype] { title: 'product' }

console.log(obj); // { title: 'product' }
```

Happy Coding..!

Comment: this is what i ended up doing to fix some tests, but it seems wrong

Comment: const groups = {...match.groups} // remove null object for test comparison

Comment: Thank You.This solves the issue but not pretty printing the JSON.

Comment: Many thanks. It's 1:30am. And struggling with very basic tasks getting done in Javascript. They told me it's rapid and fast development.

Answer (score 15):

I get some problem and my terminal showed me below explanation

`body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at express`

and i used this 
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))`

or

you are running a version of Express that is 4.16+ then type just

`app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))`

I think it helps you

To find out more about the extended option, read the docs or someone here has answered it well - [What does 'extended' mean in express 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960764/what-does-extended-mean-in-express-4-0)

Comment: the difference between extended:true and extended:false is the usage of the underlying parsing library.
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

It has nothing to do with the described issue (which isn't an issue).

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Object.assign` to fix your problem in the following fashion:

```js
const obj = Object.assign({},req.body)

console.log(obj)
```

It initializes a new object with `Object.prototype` and assigns all the properties of `req.body` to it.

Answer (score 7):

cos the object is based on the Null object.
I found the best way to strip this off, eg if you need an exact match for tests is to use:

```
const groups = {...match.groups} // remove null object for test comparison
```

Answer (score 6):

The below code worked for me

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 6):

Just change `{extended: false}` to `{extended: true}` it works for newer versions of body-parser.
It's working in ^1.19.0 version

Answer (score 0):

I was going through exactly the same issue and thought there was something wrong in the code.

Though making extended property for url encoded body parser works.

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

The reason behind the creating null objects is very interesting.

https://byby.dev/js-object-with-null-prototype

The above link and accepted answer helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing iOS App with Next.js though

when the request doesn't attach `Content-Type: application/json` with a header,
the object turn into `[Object: null prototype]`

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to simply iterate through the dictionary/objects's key value pairs:

```js
for (let parameter in req) {
    console.log(parameter, '->', query[parameter]);
}
```

which is what did the trick for me.

Answer (score -6):

I recommmend to use the function JSON.parse like that:

`const form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
console.log(form.title)`

Comment: isn't this the same response as @Tanzeel-saleem ?

Answer (score -6):

You can try this:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: Can you add a few words explaining how this code answers the OP's question?

Comment: the difference between extended:true and extended:false is the usage of the underlying parsing library.
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

It has nothing to do with the described issue (which isn't an issue).

Answer (score -8):

I had the same problem. I found out the problem was in my ejs file. I used this:

```
<form method="POST">
```

But with ajax i set the method to post so somehow when i submitted the form it sent an empty Object and the values i gave. When i deleted the method from ejs the problem solved.

I hope it helps