# Error: Object: null prototype issue in node js [Object: null prototype] { title: 'book' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm very new to node js, and I want my values without type of the variable.

**My below first js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/add-product' ,(req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST"><input type="text" name="title"><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>');
});

app.use('/product' ,(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.use('/' ,(req, res, next) => {
    res.send("<h1>Hello Express!</h1>");

});
app.listen(3000);
```

I enter the data in the form 'book' and on submit it's gave me output like

```
[Object: null prototype] { title: 'book' }
```

I want my output like

```
{ title: 'book' }
```

without the type of the variable or return object.

I have tried this [how to fix [Object: null prototype] { title: 'product' }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298481/how-to-fix-object-null-prototype-title-product), But it didn't work for me.
Screenshot of tried link error: https://www.screencast.com/t/0p9rtUTAsL

Please help me with this.!
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why is the output an issue for you? It’s merely informing you that the prototype of the object is `null`. Unless you require the prototype to be a specific value, this should not matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix \[Object: null prototype\] { title: 'product' }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298481/how-to-fix-object-null-prototype-title-product)

Comment: You said you tried something from the other question, but the accepted answer clearly states that this is not a problem and explains why. That makes it even more confusing what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the output you want to have :

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: This code is very helpful. :)

Answer (score -1):

Add also `bodyParser.json()` in order to create "application/json" parser, like so:

```
app.use(boydParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(boydParser.json());
```