# Trouble parsing data from Fetch api and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch, next.js

Happy Holidays!

I have the following function in a NEXT/React page:

```
async function onSubmit(values) {
    try {
      console.log(values);
      console.log(`JSON: ${JSON.stringify(values)}`);
      await postData("/api/put", values);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        redirect: "follow",
        referrer: "no-referrer",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });
      return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
    }
  }
```

The second `console.log()` gives me the the following:

```
JSON: {"name":"Tim","email":"bob@bob.com","title":"grwewdfgherwfsdhtrdfsgh","body":"gfggfdsbngfdsbfnggdffbffgds"}
```

Looks great to me and leads me to believe the `body: JSON.stringify(data)` would yeild the same result, however; on my back-end, my `request.body` is:

```
body:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     '{"name":"Tim","email":"bob@bob.com","title":"fdsfsdfsdfsdf","body":"ytgfhjtrghrtesdrew"}': '' } }
```

When I try to do `const data = JSON.parse(req.body);` i get the following error:

```
(node:21676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question. Try to take a look at the accepted answer. I think you'll find what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298481/how-to-fix-object-null-prototype-title-product

Comment: Are you using the bodyparser middleware? Example from GH page: var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})

Comment: #tomahaug, I get: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: req.body.toString is not a function when I add req.body.toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aren't you already using await to get the response? could you try to return response.json() instead of return await response.json()?

The reason I think so is that await should be used when the statement resolves in a promise. response.json() does not.

Comment: `response.json()` is async so you still want to await it
https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/240

Comment: yes, but you are awaiting on the postData() as well in your onSubmit(), so, shouldn't you return without awaiting?