# NPM (querystring or qs or query-string) module which to choose?

Tags: node.js, query-string

I haven't be able to find an answer regarding this. All three modules are very popular. All three support my use case. However, I am just really curious on what are differences between each of them.

There post somehow helps to explain [body-parser - extended option (qs vs querystring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175465/body-parser-extended-option-qs-vs-querystring)

[what the difference between qs and querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136374/what-the-difference-between-qs-and-querystring)
But it is still missing the third comparision (query-string)